# 2-dimensional array with duplicated index key

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to translate this line of code from php to asp.net

```
$subid[$value['parentid']][] = $value['id'];
```

i'm not familiar with asp.net data structure, i've tried arraylist but can't insert at [1], dictionary do not allow duplicated keys, anyone have ideas?

thanks

Comment: What this line is doing? What exactly do you need?

Comment: used for recursion      function print_option($parents,$subids,$name,$indent=0){

        foreach($parents as $parent ){
        $content.= "<option value='$parent'>".str_repeat('&nbsp;&nbsp;',$indent).$name[$parent]."</option>\n";
        if(key_exists($parent,$subids)){
            $subcontent=$this->print_option($subids[$parent],$subids,$name,$indent+1);
            $content.=$subcontent;
            }
        }
        return $content;
     }

Comment: Please add the code in the question.

Comment: You can use Dictinory like Dictionary<Tuple<List<string>, string>, string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PHP (anymore) and SO is not a translation service, but you can use

- [`List<Tuple<int, int>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

or

- [`Lookup<int, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx)

instead (assuming that your ids are ints).

---

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 1));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(2, 3));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(2, 4));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(3, 5));
```

With [`Enumerable.ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) you can create a `Lookup`.

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
```

Find all products with parent-id = 1:

```
var parentID1 = lookup[1];
foreach (var value in parentID1)
    Console.Write(value);
```

Comment: is there other search method except lookup which can search each tuple?

Comment: @hkinterview: I'm not sure whether or not you've understood my approaches. They are independent of each other, you can either use a `List<Tuple<TFirst, TSecond>>` or a `Lookup<TFirst, TSecond>`. The lookup is faster on lookups(as the name suggest), similar to a dictionary. But it allows duplicate keys. The `List<Tuple<TFirst, TSecond>>` is just another way to represent a list of pairs.

Comment: i understood, but i want to use foreach <BR>
foreach (object name in list)
        {
            Response.Write(name + "...<br>");
        }

is it possible?

Comment: ASP.NET is not ASP (or PHP), you should not use `Response.Write`. Instead you should use web databound controls like `GridView` or `Repeater`. The result of my code is not "12" but `1 and 2` because the parent-id 1 has two ids (1,2). Set a breakpoint and you'´ll see that the `foreach` is enumerated twice because two values belong to the key `1`.

Comment: Response.Write is just for testing at this time, i want to write the key & value in pair in above foreach loop, is it possible?

Comment: Of course: `int num=1;var id1 = lookup[num]; foreach (var value in id1)
                Console.Write("Key:{0} Value:{1}", num, value);`

Comment: it must define the num first?

Comment: @hkinterview: A lookup is a lookup, you get the values by providing a key, same as a dictionary. But you can also loop all keys even if it's not what a lookup is supposed to do: `foreach(var kv in lookup)
                foreach(var value in kv)
                    Console.Write("Key:{0} Value:{1}", kv.Key, value);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary with a little tweak to achieve what you want.

You create a dicionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

You add items to it like:

```
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey("myKey")) myDictionary["myKey"].Add("myItem");
else
{
myDictionary.Add("myKey", new List<string>(){"myItem"});
}
```

If you ask for a certain key, it will return a reference to the list with all related items.